# Как обрабатывать событие KeyDown в WinForms без паузы и повторений?

Tags: c#, winforms

Если в Windows Forms установить обработчик события KeyDown например на форме и нажать на клавишу и удерживать ее, событие сработает сначала с паузой а затем через установленный в системе промежуток для повторений. Можно ли получить реакцию на нажатие клавиши сразу же, без паузы и игнорировать повторяющееся событие (чтобы обработать завершение нажатия в KeyUp) ?

Answer (score 1):

Если пауза возникает перед первым нажатием на клавишу, то, согласно **[этой статье](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/894040/adjust-long-delay-in-keystrokes-appearing-due-to-windows-filterkeys)** и практическим экспериментам, в настройка специальных возможностей нужно отключить фильтрацию ввода.

---

Паузу между первым и вторым событием при зажимании клавиши, вероятно можно уменьшить где-то в недокументированных дебрях реестра, **но это затронет всю систему, а не только вашу программу**.

Эта пауза позволяет отличить случайное повторное нажатие, от целенаправленного. Случайное нажатие может возникать как по вине пользователя (руки дрожат или клавиши мелкие, а пальцы большие), так и по вине клавиатуры (дефект контакта, неудачная/поврежденная конструкция механизма клавиши). Так что убирать ее совсем не стоит, реальной пользы от нее больше чем гипотетического вреда.

Через "Центр специальных возможностей" можно только увеличить паузы, путем включения и настройки фильтрации ввода.

Для того, чтобы игнорировать повторные нажатия, используйте обычный прием с флагом: По событию `KeyDown` поднимаете флаг, по событию `KeyUp` - сбрасываете. При обработке события `KeyDown` проверяете флаг: если уже поднят, то ни чего не делаете; если сброшен - поднимаете и выполняете дальнейшую обработку нажатия.

---

Для тех, кто не знаком с понятием "флаг":

- Флаг - переменная типа `bool`, имя не имеет значения. Так как значение должно сохраняться между вызовами обработчиков событий, то флаг должен быть объявлен в классе как поле объекта, в обработчиках происходит только присваивание значений.
- Поднять флаг - присвоить значение `true`
- Сбросить флаг - присвоить значение `false`

---

Если клавиша зажата/залипла, то событие `KeyUp` между событиями `KeyDown` возникать не будет. Оно сработает только тогда, когда клавиша будет на самом деле отпущена/отлипнет.